# Difference-in-difference for multiple eco-friendly events

Tags: time-series, difference-in-difference

I am conducting one research evaluating the influence of eco-friendly events in cities (e.g., bike only for some streets on Sunday) on people's exercising habits (distance to walk in the cities). In total, I have nine events, and they were held between July 2016 and December 2018. The units of analysis are people in the studied city. I have data recording whether people join each event or not (treated or not) and records of their exercising habits (outcome variable). The spatial distribution of streets ever held these events is shown below:

[image: Spatial Distribution of Nine Eco-friendly Events in Los Angeles, U.S.]

I have noticed that the treatment (eco-friendly event) is staggered over time like this [post](https://lost-stats.github.io/Model_Estimation/Research_Design/event_study.html) investigating the influence of law in each state of the USA on suicidal rates. But I still have some specific questions:

- Unlike the state, which can only start the law once, people can actually join eco-friendly events multiple times. How do I use the Difference-in-difference model to test, for instance, whether the sixth event significantly influences people's exercising habits? People who joined the sixth event might have totally different event participation backgrounds (some have joined twice, but others did not join such an event).
- How to define the treatment group and control group? Currently, I make people belong to the treatment group if they ever joined such an event at least once. I think this definition works if I want to estimate the total effect of these nine eco-friendly events. But how should I define the treatment and control group for each event?

Thank you very much for your time and advice!

Comment: Is each eco-friendly event the same? In other words, is this a bike-only event (treatment) that occurs in some repeated on and off sequence over time?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Thank you for your comment! The policy of these nine events was the same (not allowing people to use private cars on weekends), but they were held in different regions of the studied city.